# Pointers to Functions (C++)

Tags: c++

I am studying a C++ tutorial. I can't understand this example on Pointers to Functions.
Here it is:-

```
// pointer to functions
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{ return (a+b); }

int subtraction (int a, int b)
{ return (a-b); }

int operation (int x, int y, int (*functocall)(int,int))
{
  int g;
  g = (*functocall)(x,y);
  return (g);
}

int main ()
{
  int m,n;
  int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;

  m = operation (7, 5, addition);
  n = operation (20, m, minus);
  cout <<n;
  return 0;
}
```

The lines "`m = operation (7, 5, addition);`" and "`n = operation (20, m, minus);`" are treated the same way, but while minus has been declared as a pointer to function, addition hasn't. So, how did they both work the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `addition` is `int (&)(int,int)` which can decay into a pointer of type `int (*)(int,int)` which is same as that of `operation` function's third parameter. So you can pass `addition` as third argument to the function `operation`.

The type of `subtraction` is also the same as that of `addition`. In your code, the address of `subtraction` is first stored as local variable of the compatible type, and then that variable is passed as argument to `operation` function.

In case of `addition`, it's address is not stored as local variable, instead its passed as such to `operation`. Its initializing the function's third parameter directly with the  function's address, without using any local variable.

A conversion from `int (&)(int,int)` to `int (*)(int,int)` occurs in both cases. Its just that with `substration`, the conversion occurs when initializing the local variable, and with `addition`, the conversion occurs when initializing the function parameter.

An analogy would be this:

```
void f(double a, double b) {}

int main()
{
   double x = 100;//first store 100 in a local variable
   f(x, 100);  //pass the local variable as first arg, 
               //and pass 100 as second arg without using any local variable.
}
```

Note the type of `100` is `int`, so it first converts to `double` type, which is then stored as local variable `x`, which in turn is passed to the function `f` as first argument. And the second argument `100` is passed directly to the function, so even now it first converts to `double` and then it initializes `b` (the second parameter of the function).

Again, a conversion from `int` to `double` occurs in both cases. Its just that first argument conversion occurs when initializing the local variable `x`, and second argument conversion occurs when initializing the *second* parameter of the function.

Comment: In fact, `int (&)(int, int)` would not decay into function pointer - `int(int,int)`, on the other hand, will. But other than that, very precise answer, so +1. :)

Comment: @Vitus: `int(int,int)` is same as `int(*)(int,int)`, as far as I know, there is no difference. BTW, `int(&)(int,int)` can decay into function pointer : http://www.ideone.com/YcLVj

Comment: I don't believe it _decays_ - more likely there are some other conversions going on. There are three types of decay - **lvalue to rvalue**, **array of T to pointer to T** and **function F to pointer to function F** (§4.1 through §4.3, and also §20.9.7.6, `decay` struct - in latest draft, at least). Hmmm, but on the other hand, lvalue reference behaves as lvalue...

Answer (score 5):

Using a function name as an argument parameter in a function call, or on the right-hand side of the assignment operator in C/C++, causes a conversion to a function pointer to the original function.

So for instance if you have a function like

```
void my_function(int a, int b);
```

If you use the identifier `my_function` on the right-hand side of the assignment operator like this:

```
void (*my_function_ptr)(int, int) = my_function;
```

Then `my_function` implicitly converts from a function object to a function pointer of type `void (*)(int, int)`, initializing the identifier `my_function_ptr` so that it points to `my_function`.  The same situation would also occur when passing `my_function` to another function like:

```
void another_function(int, void (*)(int, int));
another_function(5, my_function);
```

In the call to `another_function()`, the identifier `my_function` is again converted to a pointer to the original function.

Finally, keep in mind this only occurs if you simply pass the identifier name to a function argument, or put it on the right-hand side of the assignment operator. Adding a function call using the `()` symbols and an optional argument list (i.e., `my_function(5, 6)`) will evaluate the function, not cause a conversion to a function pointer.

Comment: A good answer; but it's unclear what do you mean by "C-type" of a function. Type-wise, a function is different than a pointer to a function, and this difference is visible in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

name of the function in C is resolved to its address. So this works:

```
int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions work: the third argument of "operation" must be a function pointer.

Please note that the ampersand  is optional:

```
m = operation (7, 5, &addition);
```

also works.

Answer (score 0):

By passing "addition" to operation() you're effectively assigning it to "functocall". It's exactly the same as assigning "subtraction" to "minus". They work the same way because they are the same.

The real question is, why don't you need an ampersand (&) to take the function's address?

p.s. Apart from the gratuitous use of iostream, namespace and cout, this is actually a C tutorial. Right?

Answer (score 0):

C++ provides implicit function-to-pointer conversion (see 4.3 in C++ 2003 standard). In your example, it is used both for assignment of `subtraction` to `minus` and for conversion of `addition` to the parameter type accepted by `operation`. So essentially both calls are done the same way, just in one case you explicitly created an intermediate variable of type pointer-to-function. And in both cases an optimizing compiler will simply pass the address of a corresponding function into `operation`.